# Celery worker: How to consume from all queues?

Tags: python, celery

I have

- set `CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = True`
- NOT defined `CELERY_QUEUES`
- defined `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'`  (of type direct)
- a custom router class that creates routes on the fly as shown in
  this ticket (https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/150).

I see that the new queue in the route returned by the custom router gets created which I assume is because of `CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES`.

Now in the worker node that I run, I don't pass the `-Q` argument and it consumes only from the 'default' queue which seems to be in line with the documentation -

> By default it will consume from all queues defined in the
>   CELERY_QUEUES setting (which if not specified defaults to the queue
>   named celery).

Is there any way to get my worker node to consume from ALL queues including the ones that are created dynamically?

Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The worker needs to be told about these automatically or dynamically created queues, so you need a way to get these queue names and store them maybe when you create them or get them maybe from `rabbitmqctl list_queues` if you're using RabbitMQ as the broker, and for example add a signal handler to add these dynamic queues to the workers to consume from.

For example using [`celeryd_after_setup`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#celeryd-after-setup) signal:

```
from celery.signals import celeryd_after_setup

@celeryd_after_setup.connect
def add_dynamic_queue(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # get the dynamic queue, maybe stored somewhere
    queue = 'dynamic_queue'
    instance.app.amqp.queues.select_add(queue)
```

If you always have new dynamic queues created, you can also command the workers to start consuming from these queues at runtime using:

```
#command all workers to consume from the 'dynamic_queue' queue
app.control.add_consumer('dynamic_queue', reply=True)

# command specific workers
app.control.add_consumer('dynamic_queue', reply=True, destination=[w1@example])
```

See [Adding Consumers](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#queues-adding-consumers).

I hope this helps, I'll edit the question when I get more info about this.

Comment: Thank you. That was interesting. Yes, I use RabbitMQ and I was planning on always having dynamic queues. I was hoping I could tell the worker to consume from all queues using some kind of wildcard pattern. I'm going to try your suggestions now. Question - Considering that workers can be running on different servers, with the message broker being the only common piece, how does app.control.add_consumer(...) communicate the information to workers?

Comment: @ksrini yeah I was searching the source code to find if we can use a wildcard pattern, but the method that sets the queues to consume from requires a list of queues separated by commas.
And the control commands use the broker (RabbitMQ) to broadcast the messages to the workers check the module `celery.app.control`.

Comment: your suggested approach using add_consumer control command worked! Thanks! I would like to invoke the add_consumer only if the workers aren't already consuming from that queue because add_consumer seems to take some time (about 1-2 second) if reply=True and I was planning on doing it from the router where I determine the new queue as part of the route. If I set reply=False, it is faster. Do you see any problem with invoking add_consumer even though workers could already be consuming from that queue?

Comment: @ksrini the method `Consumer.add_task_queue` that adds the queue checks if the queue is already in the list and if the worker is consuming from it, so don't worry about that.

Comment: @ksrini also while searching more about this issue, I found a post by Ask Solem the author of Celery on [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/celery-users/nfvg93EhIvw/XKPCsrUTSOgJ) answering about consuming from dynamic queues, and he said `No, you would have to add that capability to the worker by using the signals and storing the 
configuration somewhere, and load them at startup`.

Comment: that's great! It still bugs me that I will be invoking the add_consumer each time and it won't be useful except for the first time. But it is a relief to know that `Consumer.add_task_queue` performs the check. Thanks again! I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: I saw the google groups answer from @asksol. I guess in that case the user is trying to Consuming queues created dynamically upon 'restart'. I won't need to do that (store config somewhere) because of the approach I've taken (invoking add_consumer), but I'd be interested in exploring the possibility of adding that capability to the worker.